# NUMBER mistaken as BLOB

Tags: oracle, numbers

I use Oracle database, and I want to find out sentence containing "insert into" from the table
T_CARDNO_SETUP using the following:

```
select 'INSERT INTO T_CARDNO_SETUP
 (CARDTYPE, CARDNOTYPE, BEGINCARDNO, ENDCARDNO, CARDBIN, ORGANID, ORGANNAME, CARDBIE, STATUS)
 VALUES(' || '''' || CARDTYPE ||'''' || ','|| '''' || CARDNOTYPE || '''' || ','|| '''' || BEGINCARDNO || '''' || ','|| '''' || ENDCARDNO || '''' || ','|| '''' || CARDBIN || '''' || ','|| '''' || ORGANID || '''' || ','|| '''' || ORGANNAME || '''' || ','|| '''' || CARDBIE || '''' || ','|| '''' || STATUS || '''' ||');'
 From T_CARDNO_SETUP;
```

the question is that there is a filed ENDCARDNO is a kind of NUMBER, while I use the above sentences and get that the filed ENDCARDNO became BLOB kind, reporting wrong.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Execute a `DESC T_CARDNO_SETUP;` and post its results here. That would be helpful for us to see exactly what's happening in your schema.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are asking. Can you clarify by providing details of your schema, perhaps simplifying your example, showing the current output of your query, and telling us what you expect your output to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Assume, you're generating `INSERT` statements. And for a `NUMBER` column you can just ignore appending *single quotes*, so they are always considered as `NUMBER`.

```
 select 'INSERT INTO T_CARDNO_SETUP
 (CARDTYPE, CARDNOTYPE, BEGINCARDNO, ENDCARDNO, CARDBIN, ORGANID, ORGANNAME, CARDBIE, STATUS)
 VALUES(' || '''' || CARDTYPE    || '''' || ','||
             '''' || CARDNOTYPE  || '''' || ','||
             '''' || BEGINCARDNO || '''' || ','||
            /* '''' || ENDCARDNO   || '''' || ','||  */
                     ENDCARDNO   || ',' ||
             '''' || CARDBIN     || '''' || ','||
             '''' || ORGANID     || '''' || ','|| 
             '''' || ORGANNAME   || '''' || ','||
             '''' || CARDBIE     || '''' || ','||
             '''' || STATUS      || '''' ||');'
 From T_CARDNO_SETUP;
```